# How can select random data from database and display in textview?

Tags: android, sql, database

I'm making a android quotes app which use data in database. i want to display random quote in listview when i click on next button. 
By the way, how can i save my selected in each time i open my app? please help!
this is my Database class:

```
 public class SQLiteAdapter {
    public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "MY_DATABASE";
    public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "MY_TABLE";
    public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT = "Content";

//create table MY_DATABASE (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
    "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("
    + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + KEY_CONTENT + " text not null);";

private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

private Context context;

public SQLiteAdapter(Context c){
    context = c;
}

public SQLiteAdapter openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
    sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null,  MYDATABASE_VERSION);
    sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    return this;    
}

public SQLiteAdapter openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
    sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
    sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;    
}

public void close(){
    sqLiteHelper.close();
}

public long insert(String content){

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
}

public int deleteAll(){
    return sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
}

public Cursor queueAll(){
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_CONTENT};
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns, 
            null, null, null, null, null);

    return cursor;
}

public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
            CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

}
```

this is my xml file to display quote:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

  />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_width="80dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:text="Next"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is **tested and working correctly**. Good luck with your project. http://uploaded.net/file/9dqsjc9j
**Tip**: If eclipse is **missing imports** in your java file press **CTRL+SHIFT+O**

AndroidSqlite.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ....
    mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
    mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
    mySQLiteAdapter.deleteAll();

    mySQLiteAdapter.insert("A for Apply");
    // ....
    mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Z for Zoo");

    final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
        tv.setText(mySQLiteAdapter.getRandomQuote());
        }

    });
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    mySQLiteAdapter.close();
}
```

Put this in your SQLiteAdapter.java

```
public String getRandomQuote()
{
Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",
        new String[] { KEY_CONTENT }, null, null, null, null, null);

if(c.moveToFirst())
  return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTENT));
else 
  return "nothing";
}
```

Comment: there are have an error in this line: return c.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTENT). i can't fix it.

Comment: and what is the error saying if you hovering him with your mousepointer?

Comment: There's a `)` missing at the end of that line: it should be  `return c.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTENT));`

Comment: If you have lots of entries, you shouldn't use order by rand() but precalculate the line to use. See this article: http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete 
  MethodInvocation
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete

Comment: i missed a bracked in the onclick listener...eclipse give you a lot of help in fixing this little "bugs", just read the error message...is the app building correct now?

Comment: sorry, i fixed this but it didn't work. could you help me fix it, this is my source code: http://www.mediafire.com/?io2azx0h3o8ok5s

Comment: ok i will watch your code, give me half an hour for finishing some other stuff

Comment: sory, can i ask you the last question?  my table has two columns and i want display data in two text wiew with Next button, how can i do that? please help me the last time http://www.mediafire.com/?duzal4nkqavdghl

Comment: `public Cursor getRandomQuote()
    {
    return sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", new String[] { KEY_CONTENT, KEY_ID }, null, null, null, null, null);
    }`     
  
    `tv.setText(mySQLiteAdapter.getRandomQuote().getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTENT));`