# Android sqlite: Retrieving Random Data from Database

Tags: android, database, random

Been searching and using all the resources here but nothing seems to work with my project.

i need to retrieve a random data upon shaking the device.

i already have my shake detection. 
my problem is i cant retrieve a random data.

tested on a device. the application crashes.

mainactivity.java

```
DataSource DS = new DataSource(this);

public void onShake(float force) {

    // Called when Motion Detected
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Motion detected", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do something after 5s = 5000ms
            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            text.setText(DS.getRandomQuote());

        }
    }, 2000);


public String getRandomQuote() {

    Cursor c = database.query(MysqLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS,
        new String[] { MysqLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMMENT}, null, null, null, null, "ORDER BY RANDON() LIMIT 1");

    if(c.moveToFirst())
        return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MysqLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMMENT));
    else 
       return "nothing";
}
```

Already Read:

[How can select random data from database and display in textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082095/how-can-select-random-data-from-database-and-display-in-textview)

and

[How can select random data from database and display in textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082095/how-can-select-random-data-from-database-and-display-in-textview)

but doesn't work for me

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 0):

1. The function you're looking for is `RANDOM()` not `RANDON()`
2. [`query()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) takes its `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` params in separate args, without the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` keywords.

Comment: Sorry just a typo error change it to RANDOM() it crashes the application.

Comment: @FanBoy-designAnd-concept For crashes, always include the exception stacktrace from logcat in the question. That's one way to satisfy that "What does \"doesn't work\" mean" question.

Comment: got the error i think its my Query. 
NullPointerException -


Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS,
    allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

when i log this query its null.